# Azure App Service Docker Container Restart

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a Dockerized App running on the Azure App Service environment. That App runs with configurations (Application Settings) from Environment Variables. I have all the Application Settings set which are available as Env Variable within Docker. I want to know if we change Application settings will it restart the underlying docker container? So that the Docker process picks up the new values??

Comment: Yes. Changing an app setting restarts the app service, which in turn restarts the container.

Answer (score 0):

When you add, remove, or edit app settings, App Service triggers an app restart.

[image]

For ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core developers, setting app settings in App Service are like setting them in  in Web.config or appsettings.json, but the values in App Service override the ones in Web.config or appsettings.json.

We can understand more from Microsoft Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common) where it is stated that app will restart when any change in app settings.